# unable to connect to local network IP : error 404

Tags: iis, networking, localhost, ip

PING is ok .( all packets received ) 
I try to access a .NET ASP application that runs on IIS  , on localhost, on a second PC.
OS : Windows 10. 
Firewall **disabled**. 
Function Discovery Provider Host     : **started** 
Function Discovery Provider **started** 
SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support **checked** 
Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) **is disabled for my network connection** .

any suggestions?

Comment: There's no where near enough information to answer this question.  Is there machine you're trying to access a VM?  Is it on the same subnet?  How are you trying to access it?

Comment: Localhost is local accessible only. It is impossible to access from a second PC. You must give that site a valid site binding to be accessible from other machines. https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: I suggest you could also post the site binding setting for the asp web site. Then I suggest you could post the url you have used now to access the asp.net web site. Notice: You should use the server's IP address add port number to access the web application.

Comment: <bindings>  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />  </bindings>

Comment: Could you please tell me which url you have used to access the web application?

Comment: I've just used the IP address of the 2nd machine . http://192.168.1.17/

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by putting IP on static. and adding IP in host file.